# Novel with a mix of real world and gods

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm searching for a story, I believe it was a novel, in which someone answers an ad, and meets up with a group of different people in some suburban strip mall basement (I may be completely misremembering this, however). I think after some selection process, a smaller group is basically hired to steal something. One of them is a young girl. Maybe she's named Kitty or Fox, maybe not. And I think they steal a golden ball, possibly it's a magic enhancer or something. (There's a definite chance I might be conflating two books).

Because, there's a group that tries to summon a god (our modern world) and at some point, they're all in some Chateau in France, and they do a lot of research. And in the end, they're successful, maybe the God is called Fox. Anyway, he kills the old professor type and everybody in the group. Only the young girl remains alive. But not unscathed. (The god ..... her). Maybe that's her backstory, before we meet her.

Comment: That question already has an accepted answer, so why flag this as a duplicate of a newer question?

Comment: @QuestionAuthority, the operating principle on deciding which of two duplicates to close is that the target should be the "better" of the two. Age of the question is not widely regarded as a dominant factor in deciding this. In this case, the newer Q&A was judged slightly better by those voting to close -- it's not an indictment of this question so much as an attempt to ensure that future searchers benefit from the link established between different questions about the same story.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is (at least part of) the plot of *The Magician King* by Lev Grossman.  Takes place in our modern world, but where magic is real.  The god they summon in Murs, France is Reynard the Fox, who does indeed rape one of them and kill the rest.  It's possible some of your plot elements are from other books or shows.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had a feeling it might have been from Grossman's Magician trilogy, but then when I thought of it, I remembered the more Narnia elements and the school trip and turning into geese. But then the part with stealing the golden ball magic enhancer thing did put me in mind of the Magicians. I guess he used so many different elements that by remembering the Narnia/Hogwarts bits, I forgot the original bits.

Answer (score 10):

A secondary note to [Lak's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/221175/28460), is that there has recently been a TV series (2015) aired called [*The Magicians*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4254242/) in which this scene is prominently featured as the series finale of season 1. The character you remember in this case was called Julia, and may be mixing her up with the character Kady, as their story arcs intersect quite heavily. There a group of outcast members trying to find out how to learn magic without the assistance of the magic school Brakebills. This leads onto a tangent in the episode ["Have You Brought Me Little Cakes"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5346642/?ref_=ttep_ep13) trying to summon a god "Our Lady Underground"...

> which Raynard the Fox had actually laid a trap with, and the ritual actually summoned him, in which he mocks the humans, proceeds to murder all but Julia, rape her, then leave her there traumatised, surrounded by her dead friends.

If keywords like Fillory and Brakebills ring a bell, this is probably the series.

Note that my knowledge of this comes from the TV series, rather than book, so mileage may vary and according to IMDb Kady in fact does not exist in the books.

The series features heavily controversial themes, such as depression, rape, suicide, drug addiction (in the form of "magic" drugs) and a number of others...